How do I understand grouped[l].size()?
I try to understand the following code grouped[l].size() as in:
f = 10
n = 250
np.random.seed(100)
x = np.random.randint(0,2,(n,f))
y = np.random.randint(0,2,n)
fcols = [f'f{_}' for _ in range(f)]
data = pd.DataFrame(x, columns = fcols)
data['l'] = y
grouped = data.groupby(list(data.columns))
print(grouped['l'].size())

why it prints like this:
f0  f1  f2  f3  f4  f5  f6  f7  f8  f9  l
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1    1
                        1   0   1   0   0    1
                                        1    1
                                    1   1    1
                    1   0   0   0   0   0    1
                                            ..
1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1    1
                            1   0   0   0    1
                        1   1   0   0   1    1
                    1   1   0   0   0   0    1
                            1   0   1   1    2
Name: l, Length: 239, dtype: int64

I read it from official website：https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html
This is what confuses me: l has value either 0 or 1, so when it is used as group condition, the output l should only have 0 or 1 too, 2 lines in output with Length 2 (now it is Length 239). the above output in my mind should have form like this:
f0  f1  f2  f3  f4  f5  f6  f7  f8  f9  l
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1    1
                        1   0   1   0   0    2 


WHY length is 239, not 2?
WHY many f column is empty, not with any value?


"when [l] is used as group condition...", but you are not using just l as the group, you are grouping by list(data.columns), i.e. all the columns. So, just about any row is a unique combination, hence it's own group. As for the blanks: that's because in the result these values are in the index. I.e. the empty cells are the same as the cells above them (try: print(grouped['l'].size().index) and you'll see that those blanks in second rows are just also zeros. What you want to do, is simply: data.groupby('l').size().

Why length is 239, not 2?
groupby.size (which the way you use it could be replaced with value_counts) will consider the combinations of columns.
In your case, you have 239 unique combinations of all the columns out of the 250 rows.
You are not using l as grouper here but all column (list(data.columns)). To group by l you would have needed:
data.groupby('l').size()

# or
# data['l'].value_counts()

# l
# 0    130
# 1    120
# dtype: int64

Why many f column is empty, not with any value?
The "blank" values in the MultiIndex in your output are just a way to represent the values equal to the previous ones. Since groupby sorts the group by default, the indices will often be similar to the previous ones an this effect will be quite obvious.
If you use reset_index() you will see that the values are indeed there.

I also tried other index like grouped[f0].size(), and output are all the same. I guess that is because size is for each unique combination, not for an index (f0 or f1...)
